# How to block selecting links containing?

Tags: robots.txt, invision-power-board

What code do I add to Robots.txt to allow:

?app=core&module=global&section=**sitemap**&sitemap=sitemap_core_topics_4.xml.gz

But block all other links containing **?**

Current Code: Disallow: /*? blocks the above link(s) containing the keyword sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /*?app=core&module=global&section=sitemap&sitemap=sitemap_core_topics_4.xml.gz
Disallow: /*?
```